# Solve differential equation with two variables in Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink

I have a differential equation of the form:

```
xs'' = rhs * theta
```

to solve in Simulink, where **xs** and **theta** are variables and **rhs** is a numerical constant. So far, I've got this: [image]

but it's incomplete and I feel it is wrong. How can I simulate this equation in Simulink?

Regards

Comment: you said that `xs''` **is equal to** `rhs*theta`, or in other words, they are the same thing. Have you tried.... connecting them?

Comment: do you mean connecting the gain's output with the input of the first integrator in the xs chain?

Comment: Yes.... because they are the same thin in your equation, thus they must be the same "line" in simlulink

Comment: Ok, but what should go before the theta integrator?

Comment: I don't know. What do you want to simulate? Simulink is a tool to simulate (of course...) systems, including differential equations. Put whatever `theta'` you want, that `xs` (if you connect it to the scope) will tell you how it behaves.

Comment: Ok, I see. Would there be any way to include theta directly, without going through theta'?

Comment: "include it directly" ???

Comment: Directly: without passing by an integrator. That is, control input for theta, not theta'

Comment: Sorry, but are you serious? Yes, remove the integrator and add your input there. You have literally labeled what Theta is. You have built that system. Just add whatever you want wherever you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works as expected:

[image]

Thanks to @Ander Biguri!